# Maximum number of bindable descriptor sets via vkCmdBindDescriptorSets

Tags: vulkan

Is there a maximum amount of descriptor sets I can bind per draw call via vkCmdBindDescriptorSets? If yes, how do I find out the limit for my platform?

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum number of descriptor sets that can be bound to the current pipeline for an implementation can be read from the `maxBoundDescriptorSets` member of the [`VkPhysicalDeviceLimits`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/VkPhysicalDeviceLimits.html). This structure is part of the `VkPhysicalDeviceProperties` that can be queried via [`vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/vkGetPhysicalDeviceProperties.html).